# Juego de gato inteligente

Tags: java, array

Soy principiante en java y estoy haciendo un juego de gato, necesito que tenga un metodo en el cual la maquina juega al azar y otro en el cual juega calculadamente, tratando de vencer al usuario.
No tengo idea de como empezar para hacer que la maquina trate activamente de vencer al jugador en cada turno.
Este es el codigo que tengo hasta al momento, me faltan un par de cosas y limpiarlo un poco pero quiero tener por lo menos una base o idea de como implementar este metodo competitivo antes de seguir en caso de que tenga algo catastroficamente equivocado.

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class Gato
{
String tabla[][];
char jugador;
boolean ganador;
public Gato()
{
    tabla = new String[3][3];
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            tabla[x][y] = " ";
        }
    }
}

public void tablero()
{ 

    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        System.out.print("| ");
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {

            System.out.print(tabla[x][y] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public boolean jugarRandom()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int xMaq;
    int yMaq;
    boolean ganador = false;
    while(!ganador)
    {
        jugada();
    }
    return ganador;
}

public void encontrarGanadorMaq()
{
    if (tabla[0][0]== "O" && tabla[0][1]== "O" && tabla [0][2]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El ganador es la maquina ");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[1][0]== "O" && tabla[1][1]== "O" && tabla [1][2]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El ganador es la maquina ");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[2][0]== "O" && tabla[2][1]== "O" && tabla [2][2]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El ganador es la maquina ");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[0][0]== "O" && tabla[1][0]== "O" && tabla [2][0]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El ganador es la maquina ");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[0][1]== "O" && tabla[1][1]== "O" && tabla [2][1]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El ganador es la maquina ");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[0][2]== "O" && tabla[1][2]== "O" && tabla [2][2]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El ganador es la maquina ");
        ganador = true;
    }        
    if (tabla[0][0]== "O" && tabla[1][1]== "O" && tabla [2][2]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El ganador es la maquina ");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[0][2]== "O" && tabla[1][1]== "O" && tabla [2][0]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El ganador es la maquina ");
        ganador = true;
    }

}

public void encontrarGanadorUsu()
{
    if (tabla[0][0]== "X" && tabla[0][1]== "X" && tabla [0][2]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has ganado el juego");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[1][0]== "X" && tabla[1][1]== "X" && tabla [1][2]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has ganado el juego");
        ganador = true;
    }
    else if (tabla[2][0]== "X" && tabla[2][1]== "X" && tabla [2][2]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has ganado el juego");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[0][0]== "X" && tabla[1][0]== "X" && tabla [2][0]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has ganado el juego");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[0][1]== "X" && tabla[1][1]== "X" && tabla [2][1]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has ganado el juego");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[0][2]== "X" && tabla[1][2]== "X" && tabla [2][2]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has ganado el juego");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[0][0]== "X" && tabla[1][1]== "X" && tabla [2][2]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has ganado el juego");
        ganador = true;
    }
    if (tabla[0][2]== "X" && tabla[1][1]== "X" && tabla [2][0]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has ganado el juego"); 
        ganador = true;
    }
}

public void jugada()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int xMaq;
    int yMaq;        

    x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una fila de 0 a 2"));
    y = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una columna de 0 a 2"));
    tabla[x][y] = "X";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Turno de la maquina");
    xMaq = (int)(Math.random()*3)+0;
    yMaq = (int)(Math.random()*3)+0;      
    if (tabla[xMaq][yMaq] == "O" || tabla[x][y] == "X" ) {
        xMaq = (int)(Math.random()*3)+0;
        yMaq = (int)(Math.random()*3)+0;
        tabla[xMaq][yMaq] = "O";
    }
    else
    {
        tabla[xMaq][yMaq] = "O";
    }  
    tablero();
    encontrarGanadorUsu();
    encontrarGanadorMaq();
}



 }
```

Comment: Sería bueno que agregues una descripción breve de lo que se trata el juego de gato, recuerda que hay gente de todas partes del mundo y el que podría darte una solución no tiene idea del juego

Answer (score 3):

Tu juego el "gato" me resulto dificil de sacarlo, hasta que me di cuenta que es el "tateti", como se lo llama en Argentina. Pero bueno en fin, pude solucionar tu problema.

**Problemas principales**

- Faltaba un ciclo principal que permitiera seguir introduciendo entradas mientras haya espacio disponible en la tabla (mediante un contador) o mientras no hayas ganado tu o la máquina
- Faltaba introducir un ciclo donde mientras el espacio generado automáticamente (para la máquina) no esté ocupado por un **X** o **O**, se pudiera generar otro. Lo mismo para las coordenadas ingresadas por el usuario
- Se necesitaba comprobar cada vez que el usuario o la maquina terminaban de generar una marca en el tablero, si dicho usuario u oponente habia hecho *tateti*

Las demás correcciones fueron mínimas, pero que de igual forma impactaron en la obtención del objetivo

En cuanto al código restante estaba bien hecho, por eso solo te voy a mostrar el codigo donde introduje cambios.

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  public class Gato {

    int espaciosDisponibles = 9;
    String tabla[][];
    char jugador;
    boolean ganadorMaq;
    boolean ganador;


    public Gato() {...}

    public void tablero() {...}

    public boolean encontrarGanadorMaq() {
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("O") && tabla[0][1].equals("O") && tabla[0][2].equals("O")) {
            ganadorMaq = true;
        }
        if (tabla[1][0].equals("O") && tabla[1][1].equals("O") && tabla[1][2].equals("O")) {
            ganadorMaq = true;
        }
        if (tabla[2][0].equals("O") && tabla[2][1].equals("O") && tabla[2][2].equals("O")) {
            ganadorMaq = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("O") && tabla[1][0].equals("O") && tabla[2][0].equals("O")) {
            ganadorMaq = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][1].equals("O") && tabla[1][1].equals("O") && tabla[2][1].equals("O")) {
            ganadorMaq = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][2].equals("O") && tabla[1][2].equals("O") && tabla[2][2].equals("O")) {
            ganadorMaq = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("O") && tabla[1][1].equals("O") && tabla[2][2].equals("O")) {
            ganadorMaq = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][2].equals("O") && tabla[1][1].equals("O") && tabla[2][0].equals("O")) {
            ganadorMaq = true;
        }
        return ganadorMaq;
    }

    public boolean encontrarGanadorUsu() {
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("X") && tabla[0][1].equals("X") && tabla[0][2].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[1][0].equals("X") && tabla[1][1].equals("X") && tabla[1][2].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[2][0].equals("X") && tabla[2][1].equals("X") && tabla[2][2].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("X") && tabla[1][0].equals("X") && tabla[2][0].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][1].equals("X") && tabla[1][1].equals("X") && tabla[2][1].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][2].equals("X") && tabla[1][2].equals("X") && tabla[2][2].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("X") && tabla[1][1].equals("X") && tabla[2][2].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][2].equals("X") && tabla[1][1].equals("X") && tabla[2][0].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        return ganador;
    }

    public void jugada() {

        int x;
        int y;
        int xMaq;
        int yMaq;

        //Mientras no haya más espacios para jugar y no haya ganado ninguno
        while (espaciosDisponibles > 0 && !ganador && !ganadorMaq) {

            boolean espacioOcupado;

            do {
                //Verifica si hay por lo menos un espacio el que ocupar
                if (espaciosDisponibles > 0) {
                    x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Fila: 0 - 1 - 2"));
                    y = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Columna: 0 - 1 - 2"));
                    if (!tabla[x][y].equals("O") && !tabla[x][y].equals("X")) {
                        tabla[x][y] = "X";
                        espaciosDisponibles = espaciosDisponibles - 1;
                        espacioOcupado = true;
                    } else {
                        espacioOcupado = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    espacioOcupado = true;
                }
            } while (!espacioOcupado);
            //Cada vez que se ingresa una posicion, se debe imprimir el tablero y verificar si ganamos
            tablero();
            ganador = encontrarGanadorUsu();
            ganadorMaq = encontrarGanadorMaq();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Turno de la maquina");
            //Mientras el espacio generado (x,y) automaticamente esta en uso se generara otro
            do {
                if (espaciosDisponibles > 0) {
                    xMaq = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
                    yMaq = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
                    if (!tabla[xMaq][yMaq].equals("O") && !tabla[xMaq][yMaq].equals("X")) {
                        tabla[xMaq][yMaq] = "O";
                        espaciosDisponibles = espaciosDisponibles - 1;
                        espacioOcupado = true;
                    } else {
                        espacioOcupado = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    espacioOcupado = true;
                }
            } while (!espacioOcupado);
            //Cada vez que se genera una posicion, se imprime la tabla y se verifica si la maquina gano
            tablero();
            ganadorMaq = encontrarGanadorMaq();
            ganador = encontrarGanadorUsu();
        }
    }

    public void verificarGanador() {
        if (ganador) {
            System.out.println("Ganaste!!");
        } else if (ganadorMaq) {
            System.out.println("Gano la maquina!");
        } else if (espaciosDisponibles == 0) {
            System.out.println("Empate");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gato gato = new Gato();
        gato.jugada();
        gato.verificarGanador();
    }
}
```